# MKMapView overlay Polyline is drawn on top of road label

Tags: ios, dictionary, mkmapview, overlay, google-directions-api

I am making the navigation application by drawing a direction between 2 points. I successfully archive the functionality.

But the direction line is drawn on top of the road label and that label cannot be read as show in the picture below.

[image]

this is my code to draw overlay

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKPolylineView *overlayView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
    overlayView.lineWidth = 10.0f;
    //overlayView.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
    overlayView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return overlayView;
}
```

I can overcome this with a transparent line but it is not the efficient way.

The best way is to draw the line between the map layer and label layer of MKMapView but i don't know how can i archive that.

So any help please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you are writing this for iOS maps (not google maps as you tagged the question) and using iOS 7 then when you add the overlay to the map view you have the option of defining which level it is on `addOverlay:level:`. The levels are defined in the [MKMapView class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MKOverlayLevel)

```
[theMapView addOverlay:theOverlay level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];
```

Comment: do we have any way to specify the overlay level on ios6

Comment: No, that function was only added in iOS 7.

Comment: @Craig Could you check out my overlay question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558591/animated-gif-not-working-in-mkmapview-overlay-using-mkoverlayrenderer?noredirect=1#comment30789828_20558591

Comment: Sorry Gavin, I can't help with that one. I think Incanus is probably right.